# Anyway to know in perl if file is modified without polling?

Tags: perl

I just want to get some sort of notification in my perl script when particular file is modified.

Is there any other way rather than just polling it constantly?

Comment: If you do not want to poll you need the system (or another tool) to notify you. Which system and file system are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good way to wait until a file updated and then read from it in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367413/what-is-a-good-way-to-wait-until-a-file-updated-and-then-read-from-it-in-perl)

Answer (score 5):

[**Win32::ChangeNotify**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aChangeNotify), **[Linux::Inotify2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux%3a%3aInotify2)**

[AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aFilesys%3a%3aNotify): Check out the section which says "Why Another Module For File System Notifications".

Excerpt:

> AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify exists because I need a way to simply tie
>   the functionality those modules provide into an event framework.
>   Neither of the existing modules seem to work with well with an event
>   loop. Filesys::Notify::Simple does not supply a non-blocking interface
>   and File::ChangeNotify requires you to poll an method for new events.

Comment: Actually, Is there any other way than inotify2 because my generated RPM will be installed on the node. So I don't think so inotify2 will be installed on it?

Comment: Try AnyEvent::Filesys::Notify